# Number theory proofs relating to units

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

What is a counterexample for the following proposition:

> If $u \in U_m$ has order $n_1$ and $u_2 \in U_m$ has order $n_2$ then $u_1\cdot u_2$ has order $\mathrm{lcm}(n_1,n_2)$.

Here, $U_m$ denotes the unit group of $\mathbb Z_m$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice $2\in U_3$ have order $2$, but $2\cdot 2 = 4\equiv_ 3 1$ have order $1\ne\mathrm{lcm}(2, 2)=2$.